# Positioning layout between two other elements

Tags: android-layout

I want to pin a layout between two elements: text and a button.

```
<RelativeLayout>
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/forecast"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50sp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="egegegeg"
        android:textColor="@color/logo_color"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/forecast_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200sp"
            >
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:srcCompat="@raw/yaya"
                android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="50sp"

                android:contentDescription="@string/image" />
    </LinearLayout>

<Button
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="120sp"

        android:text="@string/search_button"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/light_blue"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

That is how it should be

[image: That is how it should be]

I tried setting layout_below and layout_above for LinearLayout but LinearLayout just flattened out. The idea is this. Pin the button and the text so that the size of the layout between the elements changes on different screen sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will solve your problem and the key point is, your linearLayout's height must be 0dp, so it will get bigger and smaller:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/forecast"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="egegegeg"
        android:textColor="@color/logo_color"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/forecast_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/forecast"
        android:layout_above="@id/search">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:srcCompat="@raw/yaya"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="50dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/image" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="120dp"
        android:text="@string/search_button"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/light_blue"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And another thing you should know is with textSize you must use "sp", and with margin you must use "dp".

Comment: That helped. The problem was solved by one line android:layout_alignParentBottom="true".
I was trying to make a button below the text using layout_below but needed to apply alignment to the bottom of the parent.